# Laravel duplicate email

Tags: php, laravel

I've declared in my user migration that a user has to be unique:

```
$table->string('email', 30)->unique();
```

But when I make a user for the first time in postmen I receive the following error:

```
{
  "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'james@gest.com' for key 'user_email_unique' (SQL: insert into `user` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `displayname`, `email`, `phonenumber`, `birthdate`, `profilepicture`, `suspended`, `role_id`, `company_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (james, egen, james egen, james@gest.com, 0628383493, , , 1, 1, 1, 2016-05-06 13:03:31, 2016-05-06 13:03:31))",
  "code": "23000",
  "status_code": 500,
```

When I look into my database the user is made so why does it give me that error?

**Controller:**

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $result = $this->userRepo->store($request);

        if (!$this->userRepo->store($request) != null) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Gebruiker is succesvol aangemaakt'], 200);
        }
        return response()->json(['message' => $result], 406);
    }
```

**userRepo:**

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validateUser($request);

        if(!$validator != null)
        {
            $user = new User([
                'firstname'             => $request->firstname,
                'lastname'              => $request->lastname,
                'displayname'           => $request->displayname,
                'email'                 => $request->email,
                'phonenumber'           => $request->phonenumber,
                'birthdate'             => $request->birthdate,
                'profilepicture'        => $request->profilepicture,
                'suspended'             => $request->suspended,
                'role_id'               => $request->role_id,
                'company_id'            => $request->company_id
            ]);

            $user->save();
            return null;
        }
        return $validator;
    }
```

I'm using dingo and JWT-Auth.

Comment: Kindly add your `validateUser()` function. Plus, just adding unique is not enough, you've to add unique validation in request or `validator::make()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look:

```
`if(!$validator != null)`
```

You don't need double negation. You can just give:

```
`if(is_null($validator))`
```

Thats way you get double `save` action.